# How to implement neural networks for the Pendulum Swing-Up Environment

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, deep-rl

I have recently completed the [Prediction and Control with Function Approximation](https://www.coursera.org/learn/prediction-control-function-approximation) course on Coursera, which is part of a reinforcement learning specialisation from the University of Alberta.

One of the assignments was to implement average reward softmax actor-critic for the pendulum swing-up environment. My completed notebook of the assignment can be found [here](https://github.com/Stoops-ML/temp/blob/main/Average_Reward_Softmax_Actor-Critic.ipynb).

In the assignment features of the actor and critic are learned using tile coding. My goal is to replace tile coding with neural networks.

Unfortunately, I cannot share the complete code of my current attempt because it uses some propriety code of the company I work for. However, the agent step is *more or less* defined as:

```
def step(
        self, reward: float | FLOAT_TYPE, deg_az_diff: npt.NDArray[FLOAT_TYPE]
    ) -> int:
        """A step taken by the agent.
        Args:
            reward (float): the reward received for taking the last action taken
            state (Numpy array): the state from the environment's step based on
                                where the agent ended up after the
                                last step.
        Returns:
            The action the agent is taking.
        """

        # Compute delta using Equation (1)
        # with torch.no_grad(): we still want to do training on the delta
        self.model_critic.eval()
        delta = (
            reward
            - self.avg_reward
            + self.model_critic(
                torch.tensor(deg_az_diff).float()
            )
            - self.model_critic(
                torch.tensor(self.prev_deg_az_diff).float()
            )
        )

        # update critic weights
        self.model_critic.train()
        self.optimiser_critic.zero_grad()  # zero the gradient buffers
        delta.backward()
        self.optimiser_critic.step()

        # update average reward using Equation (2)
        self.avg_reward += self.avg_reward_step_size * delta.item()

        # update actor weights using Equation (4) and (6)
        self.optimiser_actor.zero_grad()  # zero the gradient buffers
        softmax_prob = self.model_actor(
            torch.tensor(deg_az_diff).float()
        )
        loss = delta.item() * (
            0 - softmax_prob
        )  # don't back propagate through critic https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137128
        loss[self.last_action] = delta.item() * (1 - softmax_prob[self.last_action])
        loss = torch.sum(
            loss
        )  # TODO perhaps better performance if using separate optimiser for each weight
        loss.backward()
        self.optimiser_actor.step()

        # set current_action by calling self.agent_policy with active_tiles
        current_action = self.policy(deg_az_diff)

        self.prev_deg_az_diff = deg_az_diff
        self.last_action = current_action
        return self.last_action
```

The above code can primarily be broken down into the following steps:

1. Calculate one-step bootstrapped return `(+1−¯+̂ (+1,))` subtracted by current state-value `(̂(,))`, which gives `= + 1 − ¯ + ̂(+1,) − ̂(,)`
2. Update the critic neural network
3. Update the average reward
4. Update the actor neural network

The problem I am facing is that after 100,000+ steps the agent doesn't learn very much: the softmax probabilities have moved slightly but not by much. I believe that this the network should learn in far fewer steps because in another assignment from the course on Semi-gradient TD with a Neural Network (completed assignment can be found [here](https://github.com/Stoops-ML/temp/blob/main/Semi-gradient_TD_with_a_Neural_Network.ipynb)) the agent learns meaningful actions within 5,000 steps.

I'm looking for feedback as to why my agent is not learning. As I am new to the field any advice is appreciated (as well as on improving this post).

#### Further Details on the Project

My project is actually a 3D version of the pendulum swing-up environment: I have a camera whose line of sight should capture as many points as possible (the points are close together). The reward is therefore based on the three-dimensional difference between the average location of the points and the camera's line of sight: delta azimuth, delta elevation, and delta range (which is zero effectively). The three-dimensional delta for each point is then normalised, averaged, made absolute and finally multiplied by -1 to produce the reward of the current camera position in azimuth and elevation.

The neural networks receive as input the three-dimensional difference between the camera's line of sight and all points, which is a matrix of size (num_points, 3). The critic outputs one value (reward), and the actor outputs two (probability of turning the camera in the positive and negative azimuth directions).

The neural networks have the following layers:

1. 2D convolution: creates multiple channels and the kernel reduces the delta from a 3D matrix to a 1D vector
2. 2D convolution: creates more channels
3. Flatten
4. Linear
5. Linear: output dimension is 1 for critic and 2 for the actor
6. Apply softmax on the actor's output